# Palindrome exercise returns true even if array isn't palindrome?

Tags: java

the array spells out radar. If i change the last letter (r) to k, for example, it says the array is still a palindrome, but it's not. I've been trying to fix this for hours. Any suggestions?

```
char a1[] = {'R', 'A', 'D', 'A', 'K'};
boolean response = false;
for (int i = 0; i < a1.length / 2; i++)
{
  if (a1[i] == a1[a1.length - 1 - i])
  {
    response = true;
  }
  else
  {
    response = false;
  }
}
System.out.println(response);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to `break` in your `else`, otherwise in the next iteration the `response` again becomes `true`:

```
else {
    response = false;
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

We can say that even if one equality check fails, the array is not a palindrome.
Therefore you need to break the loop then and there only.

```
char a1[] = {'R', 'A', 'D', 'A', 'K'};
boolean response = true;
for (int i = 0; i < a1.length / 2; i++)
{
  if (a1[i] != a1[a1.length - 1 - i])
  {
    response = false;
    break;
  }
}
System.out.println(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier if you use a nested loop instead

```
char a1[] = {'R', 'A', 'D', 'A', 'K'};
    boolean isPalindrome=true;

    for (int i = 0; i < a1.length-1; i++) {
        for (int j = a1.length-1; j >=0; j--) {

            if(a1[i]==a1[j])
                isPalindrome=true;
            else
                isPalindrome=false;

        }
    }
    System.out.println(isPalindrome);
```